# accessing bit strange JSONObject in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I would like to access a strange JSONObject in java, but it is bit strange and I am stuck. This is how JSON Object looks like

```
{"a":{"11":[{"name":"\"test\"","value":55}]},"b":{"11":[{"name":1,"value":107}]},"c":{"11":[{"name":"test3","value":07}]},"d":{},"e":{}}
```

I am trying to access this like this but do not have idea how to access these "11" coz it is variable and could be any number.

```
Log.d(TAG, "A Object"+ main.getJSONObject("a"));
```

Comment: It's ugly when they do that, instead of an array, but not hard to handle.  Read it as a Map, then ask for the list of key values in the Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about getting all key names using [`getNames()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getNames(org.json.JSONObject)) and moving on from there?

In Android it is [names()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names())

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you probably should use a JSONReader and handle the keys name as you want.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
reader.beginObject();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
   String name = reader.nextName(); // a, b or c

   reader.beginObject();
   while (reader.hasNext()) {
       String name = reader.nextName(); // 11 or whatever
       reader.beginArray();
       ...
   }
   reader.endObject();
}
reader.endObject();
```